# User Access Audit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with a c# MVC website that has been developed over the course of several months by different people.  The site is quite big and uses the .NET membership facilities regulate user access to various features.

I have now been tasked with a security audit, to list what users or roles have access to which features.  I can do this by hand, but given the large number of controllers and their actions, it would be easier if I could do this with code.  I am at a loss on how to even begin.

So, in short, how do I get a list of all the controllers on a site, their actions, and determine which, if any, users/roles have access to them?

Comment: Clearly, you can use reflection to get the methods. Also implement a custom attribute that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` to perform any checks necessary. My solutions usually include annotating the methods with functional permissions, instead of reflecting every method, which are difficult to figure out what they do in larger projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little reflection to get controller methods. You can get your controllers:

```
var controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(Controller));
```

where `Controller` is the standard base class; if you've got your own custom base controller you can use that instead. This assumes you're running this code within the app; if that's not the case then replace `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` with the appropriate logic to find your app's assembly. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is easier, so I'd say to just add a function to do this somewhere in your admin-only area, if there is such a thing.

That line above will give you an array of `System.Type` objects for your controllers. From there, `foreach (var TController in controllers)` through them and get their methods:

```
var actions = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(typeof(TController)).GetCanonicalActions();
```

This gets you an array of [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) objects, from which you can use `GetFilterAttributes()` and `GetCustomAttributes()` to see what attributes are on that method - you're mostly looking for `AuthorizeAttribute`, `AllowAnonymousAttribute`, and your custom auth stuff. The `ReflectedControllerDescriptor` has these methods as well, for attributes applied to the entire controller instead of per-method.

Once you know which auth-related attributes are set, you can inspect the properties of those methods to see what they're set to. For example, `AuthorizeAttribute` exposes a `Roles` property, so for a method marked `[Authorise("admin", "superuser")]` you'll get a string containing those terms, so with a little logic you can split it up into the individual role names and use those for grouping/sorting/whatever. For any custom attributes... well, that depends on how you've implemented them, but if they don't expose what you need you can always edit them so they do.

If your methods use something like `User.IsInRole` internally... well, I'm not sure there's a way to find that programmatically. You might be stuck using Call Hierarchy view or Find All References to see where that sort of method is being accessed, so you can sift through manually.

Meanwhile, as part of this audit it's probably worth logging what's actually being accessed, if you don't already. In my projects, I tend to implement an action filter inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute`, using some logic that inspects the attributes as described above, and using the `ActionDescriptor` and `HttpContext.User` that get passed in as part of the filter context to record what action is being accessed and who's accessing it.